# How to get fprint working for su, it does for sudo

Tags: fingerprint, pam

Using Manjaro-KDE, my fingerprint reader is working for login and sudo, but not for su; after $su its asks for password. How to get this fixed? My configurations in /etc/pam.d:

```
#%PAM-1.0
# sudo: next line added, works
auth        sufficient      pam_fprintd.so

auth        include         system-auth
account     include         system-auth
session     include         system-auth

#%PAM-1.0
# su: next line added, asks for password
auth        sufficient      pam_fprintd.so

auth        sufficient      pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
#auth       sufficient      pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
#auth       required       pam_wheel.so use_uid
auth        required       pam_unix.so
account     required       pam_unix.so
session     required       pam_unix.so
```

Answer (score 2):

> after $su its asks for password

You should try

```
$ su YOUR_USERNAME
```